# Linux Mint 21 - problems with RealTek PCIe SD card reader

Tags: linux, linux-mint, linux-kernel, drivers, sd-card

I operate an HP Envy x360 15m series laptop with an AMD processor, which has a builtin slot for Secure Digital. However, inserting cards is not noticed, not even logged in the kernel ring, when running Linux Mint 21, based on Ubuntu 22.04.

Selected output from `lspci` is as follows:

```
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5228 (rev 01)
        DeviceName: Realtek PCIE CardReader
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 888a
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 8
        Memory at fcf00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
        Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Capabilities: [158] L1 PM Substates
        Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
```

The hardware is working correctly, as confirmed by booting to Windows. I have found no reports of problems with this device under Linux, yet, I am unable to use it effectively.

I have tried kernel versions 5.13, 5.17, and 5.18.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troubleshooting a different issue, I discovered a file with the following contents called `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rts5229.conf`:

```
blacklist rtsx_pci
install rtsx_pci /bin/false
```

I know nothing about how it appeared on my system, why a  rule was created that happens specifically to target a device actually on my system.

I would be very appreciate if anyone has thoughts about how such a file might have been created.

The issue I was actually troubleshooting was my AMD GPU, the driver for which also was mysteriously blacklisted in the same way (`blacklist-amdgpu.conf`).